# Changing local date affects saved date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to save the current date in the date column in my database table. When changing my local time in control panel, the current date saved in the table is not the actual current date. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you running this on a localhost, or on a server online somewhere? If the former, if you change the time of the computer in control panel, you also change the time for the server you're running. If you're running this online somewhere, changing the local time should not affect the server time. Unless you **want** the server to always store local time? In that case, you're asking the wrong thing.

Comment: sooo thats how it works. i got it. thanks for this

Comment: Are you talking about time zones?

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have a date and time on its own. `time()` returns the current timestamp of the server's time. Depending on your operating system, it may well be that you (i.e. the user that runs your script's process) are actually not allowed to change the server date and time.